# "unresolved external symbol" referencing one class from another

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to do something (as a C++ noob) that I thought should be easy: reference one class from another.  For some reason, I'm getting an error:

> Error 6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float * __thiscall Foo::Test(void)" (?Test@Foo@@QAEPAMXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl Test(void)" (?Test@@YAXXZ)    Bar.obj

**Foo.h**

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(void);
    ~Foo(void);
    float* Test();
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"
float* Test()
{
    return new float[0];
}
```

**Bar.h**

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(void);
    ~Bar(void);
    void Test();
};
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Foo.h"
void Test()
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    foo->Test();
}
```

Why won't the compiler let me reference the class **Foo** from **Bar**?  I have no idea what this error means, nor any clue how to debug it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include "Foo.h"
float* Test()
{
    return new float[0];
}
```

Should be:

```
#include "Foo.h"
float* Foo::Test()
{
    return new float[0];
}
```

Your version simply defines a free function `Test`, not the same as the member function `Foo::Test`.

An `Unresolved external symbol` error means that the compiler is telling you *hey, you told me I would find the definition of this thing, but I looked and couldn't find it anywhere*.  Essentially, you have lied to it, and it called you out.

That other junk is the calling convention (`__cdecl`, `__thiscall`) and the mangled (actual) function name (`?Test@@YAXXZ`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `Foo::Foo()`, `Foo::~Foo()` and similarly for `Bar`. Furthermore, the implementation of `float* Test()` should be

```
float* Foo::Test() { ... }
```

But you should really refrain from returning pointers to dynamically allocated objects to the caller. Use smart pointers, of `std::vector<float>` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't implement member functions of `Foo` and `Bar` but free stand Test functions. To implement member functions outside class, you need to provide class name with scope resolution.

Update:

Foo.cpp

```
float* Test()
{
  return new float[0];
}
```

to

```
float* Foo::Test()
{
  return new float[0];
}
```

Bar.cpp

```
void Test()
{
  Foo* foo = new Foo();
  foo->Test();
}
```

To:

```
void Bar::Test()
{
   Foo* foo = new Foo();
   foo->Test();
}
```

You also need to implement `~Foo(void)`, `~Bar(void)` as well